# Cleanup SharePoint online managed and crawled properties

Tags: sharepoint-online, search, managed-property, crawled-property, search-schema

I think I made a mess of my SharePoint search schema with too many properties with similar names. Is there a way to clean the sharepoint managed and crawled properties as if it was a new tenant? I don't want to create a new tenant just to have a clean search schema.

Answer (score 0):

In SharePoint Online, **crawling happens automatically based on the defined crawl schedule**. And we can not delete crawled property.

More information, please refer to this article:

- [Manage the search schema in SharePoint](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/manage-search-schema)